# c# How to deal with Newline character, when moving strings to resources for Localization purpose?

Tags: c#, localization, newline, multilingual

I am writing a application in c#.For the localization purpose, I am moving all of my strings to resources.

Some example of strings:

1. `"First sentence.\n Second sentence."`
2. `"wait..."`

In first string there is newline character `"\n"`.Should I move the newline character to resources too.

In second string, should I move the three dots to resources or should I split string in to two parts like `"wait" + "..."` and move only `"wait"` to resources.

I am using **Google-translate** to translate strings to other languages and i am afraid that newline character `"\n"` will not be translate well to other language by **Google-translate**, hence my hesitation to move newline character to resources.

This is my first take at localization.So suggest if you any further ideas or point me out in right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe \n will not be treated as an escape character in the rendered text.

if the number of resource entries is small, you can use **shift + enter** to add a new line.

Another option is to replace `\n` by `{0}` and then use `String.Format()` to insert a new line where needed.

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I was  looking for.I have replaced all `\n` by `{0}`. In Zeta Resource editor there is option to ignore   `{0} {1} {2}` etc.  from being translated by **Google-Translate**.

Comment: shift+enter may encode as `\r\n`, the second option is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the best approach is to avoid splitting up localisable strings wherever possible - splitting up a string only increases the chance that it won't be possible to correctly localise the string.

Comment: This is right in case if you are translating manually.But i am using this tool [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html).This tool automatically translates your resource strings in to other languages automatically using **Google-translate**.