# how to make string returned by ResourceManager.GetString not verbatim

Tags: c#, winforms, escaping

Okay, I have a string

```
string textToShow = "this\nrocks"
```

which when put in label in winforms window will then show

```
this
rocks
```

Which is the result I'd like to get. Now, instead of setting the textToShow in the code, I set it in the resource file. When I tried to get the value from resource file using

```
Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("textToShow");
```

the whole string instead will be treated as verbatim, showing

```
this\nrocks
```

when put in a label in a winforms window. This is not the result i'm looking for. What's the best way to store strings with special characters in resource file then? I can do string replace for every special characters, like

```
string.Replace(@"\n", "\n");
```

but then I need to replace every special characters whenever I call method ResourceManager.GetString, which I think is not the most elegant solution. If there is some ways to make string returned from method ResourceManager.GetString not verbatim, please do tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was already answered here: [StackOverflow: How to deal with newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626767/c-sharp-how-to-deal-with-newline-character-when-moving-strings-to-resources-for)

Basically you have two useful options:

Use `shift + enter` in the resource manager text editer to add a new line.

Or use `String.Format()` to replace `{0}` with `\n` on read.

Answer (score 1):

The .Net 4.5 framework has the unescape functionality as shown here:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Regex.Unescape(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("textToShow"));
```

solves your issue. Now you can use `\n` and `\u` in the resource files.

Answer (score 0):

On the resource editor type "this<**shift+enter**>rocks" as the resource value.